# how can i store value from toggle button

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

how can i get value in PHP code using bootstrap toggle button and after that i want to add hidden field also for edit page in which toggle button remember status (Locked/Unlocked). My code is:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-one">
<script>
  (function() {
      $('#toggle-one').bootstrapToggle({
          on: 'Locked',
          off: 'Unlocked'
      });
   })
</script>
```

Comment: in PHP? So you're posting a form?

Comment: You should be more specific. You can't read data of an element from PHP unless you send the data with post or get

Comment: I'm using method="post"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the value(s) to a PHP script/page, a very convenient way is to make an AJAX call to a PHP page, giving it the values you want via GET or POST.

Then on the PHP page you can retrieve those values with $_POST[] or $_GET[].

Don't forget that JS/JQuery are on client side, while PHP is on server side.